# Magento2: Is Magento Community provide a Cloud?

Tags: magento2, cloud, discussion

Like Magento EE support Cloud.
In the same way, Does Magento CE give us Cloud?

And what is the benefit if I choose Magento EE with Cloud. And What if not go with cloud?

Can anyone please help

Answer (score 2):

No official community cloud edition

If you chose CE the closest you are going to get us using a cloud based hosting provider. Just search cloud hosting. Although potentially this is just another way of saying shared hosting.

The idea behind cloud hosting is that it is easily upscalable as your business grows.

The difference in Magento terms is the same as choosing between EE and CE. They refer to it as commerce and open source now.

https://magento.com/compare-open-source-and-magento-commerce

If your not in the cloud but got your own dedicated box for example you've got a lot more control over what is used / installed.

But with this comes greater responsibility for your actions. For example there will be a lot more configuration required.

So after doing your research you need to ask yourself what will work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thought.